# optimize mysql count in 31M data

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, count

Is there any idea to optimize this sql that it takes several minutes to count 11M rows ?Any ideaes, I will be very grateful.

mysql version :
5.7.15-log

```
explain SELECT count(id) FROM consumer.class:
```

it responsed

> Select tables optimized away

(not use any index ,It seems that the mysql querier is automatically optimized,but it is too slow!!)
then i use `force index(primary)`,I get the same result,If i want use force index,I must add `where id > 0` ,Run with the sql of

```
SELECT count(`id`) FROM `consumer`.`class` force INDEX (`id`)
```

will not use the index too,It is no effect,only like this can use the force index:

[image]

Even if the use of the index, the query also takes a few minutes, and sometimes can not even get mysql return. This is unacceptable

show profile(this picture is reduced to 200,000 rows results,31M can not get mysql's response):
[image]

I found that "Sending data" operate use a lot of time,But I don't know how to optimize.

Comment: Is it any better if you use `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(id)`?

Comment: @Barmar no beeter yet,The execution time is almost the same,It seems that the mysql querier is automatically optimized with * and others

Comment: InnoDB doesn't cache the table size. The only way for it to do `COUNT(*)` is by scanning the entire table.

Comment: Yes,I know this, if using count, maybe myISAM behaves better in this case, but it does not support the transaction.I would like to know there is any other idea for this?

Comment: I gave you a link to another question that has answers.